# Populate nested object with MongoosJS, NodeJS and AngularJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a problem with getting nested objects in a model.
I have a model restaurant, where i am referencing an article. This is just an demo for me to test how this is working, but i am not getting it.. :(

ah.. i am using meanjs..

here is my restaurant model..

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/**
 * Restaurant Schema
 */
var RestaurantSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Restaurant name',
        trim: true
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        default: 'description is here'
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    article: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Article'
    }
});

mongoose.model('Restaurant', RestaurantSchema);
```

This is my Article model.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/**
 * Article Schema
 */
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        required: 'Title cannot be blank'
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }
});

mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
```

this two methods are in the nodejs backend restaurant controller:

```
exports.list = function(req, res) { Restaurant.find().sort('-created').populate('article').exec(function(err, restaurants) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(restaurants);
        }
    });
};

exports.restaurantByID = function(req, res, next, id) { Restaurant.findById(id).populate('article').exec(function(err, restaurant) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (! restaurant) return next(new Error('Failed to load Restaurant ' + id));
        req.restaurant = restaurant ;
        next();
    });
};
```

I have then an angular controller method to safe a new restaurant and an article, which is working. When i am accessing `"http://localhost:3000/#!/articles"`. But when i am trying to get for example the title out, it is not working.

I am creating my restaurant and article this way:

```
// Create new Restaurant
        $scope.create = function () {
            // Create new Restaurant object

            var newArticle = new Articles({
                title: this.articleTitle
            });
            newArticle.$save();

            var restaurant = new Restaurants({
                name: this.name,
                desc: this.description,
                article: newArticle._id
            });

            // Redirect after save
            restaurant.$save(function (response) {
                $location.path('restaurants/' + response._id);

                // Clear form fields
                $scope.name = '';
            }, function (errorResponse) {
                $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
            });
        };
```

this is in my create view:

```
<div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
                        <input type="text" data-ng-model="articleTitle" id="article" class="form-control" placeholder="artikel" required>
                        <input type="text" data-ng-model="description" id="description" class="form-control" placeholder="desription" required>
                    </div>
```

and this is in my list view

```
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-ng-bind="restaurant.name"></h4>
            <h3 class="list-group-item-heading" data-ng-bind="restaurant.article"></h3>
            <h3 class="list-group-item-heading" data-ng-bind="restaurant.desc"></h3>
```

the description is visible in the browser, but, nothing visible about the article. How do i get the information about the article in the restaurant object?

Probably, this is very easy, but i did not find it out..

thanks in advanced..

Comment: The interresting thing is also that i am not getting the id of the article either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i figured it out.. i made a mistake of how i am creating the article. I thougt maybe it was something wrong with article, then i created a new crud dish..

first, i am saving the dish, and in the callback i am creating the restaurant with the information i got from the callback response.. this worked for me..

```
// Create new Restaurant
        $scope.create = function () {
            // Create new Restaurant object

            var dishId = 0;
            var thisObject = this;

            var newDish = new Dishes({
                name: this.dishName
            });
            newDish.$save(function(response){
                    console.log('XX in $save: %s', response._id);
                    dishId = response._id;

                    var restaurant = new Restaurants({
                        name: thisObject.name,
                        desc: thisObject.description,
                        art: {
                            title: thisObject.artTitle,
                            content: thisObject.artContent
                        },
                        dish: dishId
                    });

                    // Redirect after save
                    restaurant.$save(function (response) {
                        $location.path('restaurants/' + response._id);

                        // Clear form fields
                        $scope.name = '';
                    }, function (errorResponse) {
                        $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
                    });
                }
            );
        };
```

and of course, i have to populate this new dish in my server controller:

```
exports.list = function(req, res) { Restaurant.find().sort('-created').populate('dish').exec(function(err, restaurants) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(restaurants);
        }
    });
};

exports.restaurantByID = function(req, res, next, id) { Restaurant.findById(id).populate('dish').exec(function(err, restaurant) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (! restaurant) return next(new Error('Failed to load Restaurant ' + id));
        req.restaurant = restaurant ;
        next();
    });
};
```

and this is my restaurant model:

```
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Module dependencies.
     */
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    /**
     * Restaurant Schema
     */

var RestaurantSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Restaurant name',
        trim: true
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        default: 'description is here'
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    article: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Article'
    },
    dish: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Dish'
    },
    art: {
        title: {
            type: String,
            default: 'HelloTitle',
            trim: true,
            required: 'Title cannot be blank'
        },
        content: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            trim: true
        }
    }
});

mongoose.model('Restaurant', RestaurantSchema);
```